# Resize rotating banner to minimum width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a rotating banner using code from unslider.com. It has 4 images. The images are 2080px wide. This is the maximum size I desire for my website. I'd like the website and the images to scale down to a minimum of 1024px. The website currently does this. (Paragraph text stops rescaling at 1024).

But the images do not. I need to figure out how to get the banner to resize down to 1024 as well.

I've got a codePen setup here to make it easier:

http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/LENvwx/

And here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>CodePen - Rotating Image Banner that resizes down to minimum size</title>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
max-width:1280px;  
min-width:1024px;
  }


.banner { 
 position: relative;
 overflow: auto; 
 width:1280px;


}

 .banner ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;  }


 .banner li { 
 list-style: none; 
 }

.banner ul li { 
float: left; 
display:block;
max-width:100%;
height:295px;


 /*     -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;*/
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
 /*     background-size: 100% 100%;*/

 }

#image1 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image1.png");
}

#image2 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image2.png");
}

#image3 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image3.png");
}


 #image4 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image4.png");
}

</style>
</head>

 <body>

 <div id="container">

<div class="banner">
<ul>
    <li id="image1"></li>
    <li id="image2"></li>
    <li id="image3"></li>
    <li id="image4"></li>
 </ul>
 </div>

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu arcu feugiat, posuere felis    vitae, malesuada nulla. Integer dapibus lacus purus. Fusce hendrerit vestibulum purus sed bibendum. Vestibulum turpis tellus, cursus in ullamcorper eget, viverra a dolor. Maecenas sed erat quis nibh iaculis rhoncus in eu mi. Vestibulum sit amet nulla molestie, venenatis magna vel, porta ligula. Phasellus dictum rhoncus diam id ullamcorper. Ut scelerisque purus ac neque semper, non eleifend arcu egestas. Curabitur lacinia est laoreet ligula volutpat, ut suscipit augue interdum. Nulla rutrum mi vel blandit suscipit. Donec ac elit et velit mattis fringilla. Mauris ac cursus massa. Integer vehicula non eros eu dapibus. Aliquam volutpat rhoncus fringilla. Nullam finibus euismod lectus quis tempus.<BR><BR>

  Quisque facilisis eros sit amet nisi malesuada, eget blandit ex convallis. Donec tellus est, placerat nec sapien id, ornare consequat nulla. Curabitur eleifend risus nec ante commodo pharetra id ut lectus. Proin ac tristique lectus. Proin ac quam a dolor auctor rhoncus. Aenean lobortis faucibus erat at sodales. Praesent non lacus quis magna mattis viverra. Integer consequat nibh diam, sed euismod elit tincidunt eget. Donec eu nunc vitae ante ultrices pellentesque sit amet quis eros. Praesent at placerat massa. Vestibulum malesuada vulputate augue a dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet leo quis justo tincidunt tempor.

 </div>

<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider();
});


</script>

</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Hmmm, well that uses `<li>`s with `background-image`s, so that might be challenging to scale both width and height the same as images would naturally with `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: I'm open to using other simple rotating banner code that works if I need to go a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width of .banner to auto, this will get the width of the parent div or window width.

In codepen it won't work, you need to test this in a html document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>CodePen - Rotating Image Banner that resizes down to minimum size</title>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
max-width:1280px;  
min-width:1024px;
  }


.banner { 
 position: relative;
 overflow: auto; 
 width: auto;


}

 .banner ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;  }


 .banner li { 
 list-style: none; 
 }

.banner ul li { 
float: left; 
display:block;
max-width:100%;
height:295px;


 /*     -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;*/
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
 /*     background-size: 100% 100%;*/

 }

#image1 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image1.png");
}

#image2 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image2.png");
}

#image3 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image3.png");
}


 #image4 {

background-image:url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/189477/image4.png");
}

</style>
</head>

 <body>

 <div id="container">

<div class="banner">
<ul>
    <li id="image1"></li>
    <li id="image2"></li>
    <li id="image3"></li>
    <li id="image4"></li>
 </ul>
 </div>

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus eu arcu feugiat, posuere felis    vitae, malesuada nulla. Integer dapibus lacus purus. Fusce hendrerit vestibulum purus sed bibendum. Vestibulum turpis tellus, cursus in ullamcorper eget, viverra a dolor. Maecenas sed erat quis nibh iaculis rhoncus in eu mi. Vestibulum sit amet nulla molestie, venenatis magna vel, porta ligula. Phasellus dictum rhoncus diam id ullamcorper. Ut scelerisque purus ac neque semper, non eleifend arcu egestas. Curabitur lacinia est laoreet ligula volutpat, ut suscipit augue interdum. Nulla rutrum mi vel blandit suscipit. Donec ac elit et velit mattis fringilla. Mauris ac cursus massa. Integer vehicula non eros eu dapibus. Aliquam volutpat rhoncus fringilla. Nullam finibus euismod lectus quis tempus.<BR><BR>

  Quisque facilisis eros sit amet nisi malesuada, eget blandit ex convallis. Donec tellus est, placerat nec sapien id, ornare consequat nulla. Curabitur eleifend risus nec ante commodo pharetra id ut lectus. Proin ac tristique lectus. Proin ac quam a dolor auctor rhoncus. Aenean lobortis faucibus erat at sodales. Praesent non lacus quis magna mattis viverra. Integer consequat nibh diam, sed euismod elit tincidunt eget. Donec eu nunc vitae ante ultrices pellentesque sit amet quis eros. Praesent at placerat massa. Vestibulum malesuada vulputate augue a dapibus. Vestibulum sit amet leo quis justo tincidunt tempor.

 </div>

<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js'></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider();
});


</script>

</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: I did as you suggested on a test page and setting banner width to auto did not work.

Comment: When I tested this in an html document on my pc, it works. But I'll try to make another fix using jQuery.

Comment: Actually, yes, on refresh, the width of the image container does get smaller, but the actual image stays the same size. The image is cut off. It's hard to tell that on my test images. Here is a link to a test page with "real" images:

http://codewelldesign.com/testT.php